# Time Complexity of Recursive Functions variable meanings

Tags: time-complexity

The general formula for time complexity is `T(n) = aT(n/c) + bn^k`

If `a > c^k`, the complexity is `O(n^log base c a)`

If `a = c^k`, `O(n^k log n)`

If `a < c^k`, `O(n^k)`

`a` is the amount of times the recursive function is called, but what do `b`, `c`, and `k` represent?

Comment: Just read the wikipedia     https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Answer (score 0):

`c` is a constant factor by which the problem size is reduced in every recursive call; e.g., for merge-sort,  we usually have `c = 2`.

The last part of your equation is usually represented by the more general `f(n)`; in your case, `f(n)` is a polynomial function with exponent `k` and some factor `b`.